# pandas cant replace commas with dots

Tags: pandas, replace

Help me plz.

I have this dataset:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1i9QwMZ63qYVlxxde1kB9PufeST4xByVQ/view

i cant replace commas (',') with dots ('.')

When i load this dataset with:

```
df = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/data.csv', sep=',', decimal=',')
```

it still contains commas, for example in the value ''0,20'

when i try this code:

```
df = df.replace(',', '.')
```

it runs without errors, but the commas still remain, although other values ​​​​in the dataset can be changed this way...

Comment: try adding regex=True to replace

Comment: I think the data type of the column you want to replace commas with is `float` and not `str`. Replace will only work with strings. Can you verify if those columns are string type?

Comment: data type is object. this code works:  df = df.stack().str.replace(',','.').unstack()

Comment: Put sample data as a text block into the post itself (it doesn't need to be the whole file, just enough of a sample to reproduce the problem). Links eventually die and become useless for future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
df = df.replace(',', '.', regex=True)
```

But keep in mind that you need to convert the columns to integer type (the ones that have the issues) because as for now they are as of type object.

You can check for those cases with the below command:

```
df.dtypes
```